# Generate a Required File using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to generate a JSON file using a JAVA script , but am not getting the expected output , can you help me generating out put of this .

Expected out put :

```
{
    "ewh5yuwe": {
        "NumCopies": "1",
        "NumPages": "10",
        "Status": "done printing",
        "Title": "demo.jpg",
        "Username": "keshavka",
        "date": "23:06 Feb 5, 15",
        "print status": "OK",
        "time": "1429036296",
        "timestamp done printing": "${__time(yyyyMMddHMS)"
    }
}
```

out put received after calling `print();` function is as below:

```
""rYajbQx":{[object Object]}"
```

code:

```
function makeid() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}
//above Code is to generate a Random variable

function test() {
    var jobid = Math.random();
    var jobkey = jobid;
    var time = new Date().getTime()
    var kes = makeid()
    var joblog = {
        "NumCopies": "1",
        "Status": "done printing",
        "Title": "demo.jpg",
        "Username": "keshavka",
        "date": "23:06 Feb 5, 15",
        "print status": "OK",
        "time": "1429036296",
        "timestamp done printing": time
    };

    json = JSON.stringify(joblog);
    console.log(joblog);
    return joblog;
}

// Above code is to generate JSON

var x = test();
console.log(x);
var y = makeid();
console.log(y);


function print() {
    a = ('{' + (test()) + '}');
    return a;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is a console.log through a web browser? I don't think this is wrong. If you print it out on Marijn Haverbeke's sandbox, I seem to get the output you desire: http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/.

Comment: Just to check, I put this in a JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/dvancuyk/4upt6hte/ and looked at the debugger tool's console in Chrome, IE 10, and Firefox and got output that you are looking for.

Comment: @derek , i got the following out put on running with sandbox u suggested and this is different than what i need  and below the function print  i have tried with  where makeid and test are two different function function print()
 {
    a=('{'+'"'+ makeid() +'"'+':'+ '{'+test()+'}'+'}'); 
     return a;
 }

Comment: i got the output twice : {
NumCopies: "1"
Status: "done printing"
Title: "demo.jpg"
Username: "keshavka"
date: "23:06 Feb 5, 15"
print status: "OK"
time: "1429036296"
timestamp done printing: 1435579042847
}
{
NumCopies: "1"
Status: "done printing"
Title: "demo.jpg"
Username: "keshavka"
date: "23:06 Feb 5, 15"
print status: "OK"
time: "1429036296"
timestamp done printing: 1435579042847
}
QbOo54D

Comment: You got the output twice b/c there are 2 console.log calls to the object in the code provided above: once in the test method itself and once in the top-level execution code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I know what you want. You want to return an object that has a property on it with the name of the id you generate and its value set to the properties listed in the code above. The main thing I would change is how the object is created. So in your test function I would make the following changes:

```
var joblog = {};
joblog[kes] = {    
   "NumCopies":"1",
   "Status": "done printing",
   "Title": "demo.jpg",
   "Username": "keshavka",
   "date": "23:06 Feb 5, 15",
   "print status": "OK",
   "time": "1429036296",
   "timestamp done printing": time 
};
```

So if you generate an id of '5YhDv7n', you would get an object of type:

```
{
  5YhDv7n:{
      ObjectNumCopies: "1",
      Status: "done printing",
      Title: "demo.jpg",
      Username: "keshavka",
      date: "23:06 Feb 5, 15",
      print status: "OK",
      time: "1429036296",
      timestamp done printing: 1435580266234
   }
}
```

I edited the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvancuyk/4upt6hte/1/) I made to reflect these changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not returning the JSON, but the object itself.

```
function test() {
    [...]

    var json = JSON.stringify(joblog);
    console.log(json);
    return json;
}
```